# VMware mount shared folder in specific folder on linux guest

Tags: mount, vmware, vmware-workstation, shared-folders, fstab

I would like to mount a VMware shared folder to a location other than the default.

The default mount path for shared folders in linux guest as of VMware Workstation 15 (2023) is: `/mnt/hfgs/[shared_folder_name]/`

**My final goal is to make docker's folder available from the host as a shared folder: `/var/lib/docker/`**

I tried:

##### 1.

`mount --bind /var/lib/docker/ /mnt/hgfs/[shared_folder_name]/`

`mount --bind /mnt/hgfs/[shared_folder_name]/ /var/lib/docker/`

The `mount` command did not return an error, but nothing seemed to change.

##### 2.

Since I had to modify **`/etc/fstab`** already to get the default `/mnt/hfgs/[shared_folder_name]/` working, I had another idea.
I renamed the shared folder to "docker" and modified the relevant line in `/etc/fstab` from this:

`vmhgfs-fuse   /mnt/hgfs   fuse    defaults,allow_other,_netdev    0    0`

to this:

`vmhgfs-fuse   /var/lib    fuse    defaults,allow_other,_netdev    0    0`

However, it "overwrote" the whole `/var/lib`, the only folder visible inside it was the shared folder[1] I named docker. While this second option could probably work if I copied the whole `/var/lib` out, made the change the copy it all back, it feels too hacky, (and possibly VMware would remove them anyway, because the other folders I copied back into `/var/lib` wouldn't be proper shared folders).

---

[1]:
Note about how VMware shared folders seem to work:

If on the guest linux I set the path in `/etc/fstab` to `/example`, the whole `example` folder becomes "overwritten" (not accessible), and the shared folders become available as `/example/shared1`, `/example/shared2`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to mount a VMware shared folder to a location other than the default.

See https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/60262.

If you have [open-vm-tools](https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools) installed, it's easiest to use a terminal shell to run:

```bash
vmhgfs-fuse .host:/SHARE DESTINATION
```

Note that mounting over `/var/lib` will hide the old contents of `/var/lib`, which is true for mounting in general, so you should mount into a subdirectory instead.  For example:

```bash
sudo vmhgfs-fuse .host:/SHARE/docker /var/lib/docker -o allow_other
```

Note that the above expects `/var/lib/docker` to be an existing directory and uses `sudo` since root privileges are required to mount to `/var/lib`.  The `-o allow_other` mount option allows non-root users to access the mount.

Alternatively, you always can just mount the shared folder anywhere and then instead create a `/var/lib/docker` symlink to point to that mount location, e.g:

```bash
sudo ln -s /mnt/hgfs/SHARE/docker /var/lib/docker
```

Comment: As you suggested I tried /usr/bin/vmhgfs-fuse .host/var/lib -o subtype=vmhgfs-fuse, but it threw back an error "No such file or directory". But apart from the error, I suspect successfully running this command would have the same effect of what I already tried, detailed in the 2.part of my question.


          Could you elaborate on the symlink part?

Comment: @hatalmasalma I've updated my answer.